# Ansible VMWare Gather ESX Hosts List

Tags: ansible, vmware

Within a given datacenter, providing (by input/variable) the ESX cluster, I would like to get the list of available ESX hosts within the cluster.

I have checked these 2 Ansible VMWare modules:

- [vmware-cluster-info](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/vmware/vmware_cluster_info_module.html#ansible-collections-community-vmware-vmware-cluster-info-module)
- [vmware-host-facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/vmware/vmware_host_facts_module.html#ansible-collections-community-vmware-vmware-host-facts-module)

Via vmware_cluster_info I can gather the list of clusters, but via the vmware_host_facts seems I have an error while querying for all the hosts within a cluster:

```
- name: Gather vmware host facts
vmware_host_facts:
  hostname: "{{ vcenter_server }}"
  username: "{{ vcenter_user }}"
  password: "{{ vcenter_pass }}"
  validate_certs: false
register: host_facts

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Connected to a vCenter system without specifying esxi_hostname"}
```

This would indicate that esxi_hostname parameter is required, although in doc it is not mentioned like that.

I believe the environment requirements are met, but here's my environment details:

```
# ansible --version
ansible 2.9.21
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Aug 13 2020, 02:51:10) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]

# pip freeze | grep pyv
pyvmomi==7.0
```

Any idea why this is failing or any idea of a different method to get a list of ESX hosts via Ansible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you will check once again module you will see that esxi name is a 'must have' to make it work

> COMMUNITY.VMWARE.VMWARE_HOST_FACTS    (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible_collections/community/vmware/plugins/modules/vmware_host_facts.py)

```
    This module can be used to gathers facts like CPU, memory, datastore, network and system etc. about ESXi host system. Please specify hostname or IP address of ESXi host system as
    `hostname'. If hostname or IP address of vCenter is provided as `hostname' and `esxi_hostname' is not specified, then the module will throw an error. VSAN facts added in 2.7
    version. SYSTEM fact uuid added in 2.10 version.
```

What I can suggest is to use inventory plugin to gather info about
all ESXi in infrastructure - community.vmware.vmware_host_inventory

another approach would be to use REST method to

```
 - name: Get hosts from vCenter
      uri:
        url: "https://{{ vmware.host }}/rest/vcenter/host"
        force_basic_auth: yes
        validate_certs: no
        headers:
          Cookie: "{{login.set_cookie}}"
      register: vmhosts
```

and then operate on variable vmhosts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [vmware.vmware_rest.vcenter_host_info](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/vmware/vmware_rest/vcenter_host_info_module.html) module to query ESXi hosts. To get just the ESXi hosts of a given cluster in a given datacenter, use:

```yaml
- name: Get ESXi hosts
  vmware.vmware_rest.vcenter_host_info:
    datacenters:
      - MyDatacenter
    clusters:
      - MyCluster
  register: esxi_hosts
```

You also have to provide authentication parameters of course, either in the task or as module defaults.

---

Be aware, the `datacenters` and `clusters` filters filter for object IDs and not for display names. An object ID for a datacenter may look like `datacenter-c2028` and for a cluster like `domain-c2021`. You have to look them up, before using this module.